# Trouble finding the correct syntax creating vars in objects

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object

Up until now I have been creating var inside the classes I made. e.g.

```
var backpack:Array = new Array("food", "water");
```

I want to create objects dynamically now like:

```
player = {};
player.backpack = ("food", "water"); // not the right syntax
```

OR

```
player = {backpack:Array = new Array("food", "water")} // not right either.
```

Any help? Thanks in advance. I can do this with simple vars like int, but can't find the answer to arrays.

Comment: Values in Array have an index which you don't have to specify, values in Object have a key that must be specified. So ['myvalue'] is correct because by default it's given the index 0 but Object have no index so they must specify their key as well. {myvalue:'myvalue'}

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript's generic object properties don't have any variable type associated with them. You assign them one of the following ways.

### Example 1

```
player = {backpack: new Array("food", "water")};
```

### Example 2

```
player.backpack = new Array("food", "water");
```

### Example 3

```
player["backpack"] = new Array("food", "water");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use square brackets to define literal arrays. Not only is it shorter, but it's also faster (see [this post](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=214186)).

The correct syntax for your two examples are

```
player = {};
player.backpack = ["food", "water"];
```

and

```
player = {backpack: ["food", "water"]};
```

Also, if you find it easier, you can use it in the first line of code you wrote.

```
var backpack:Array = ["food", "water"];
```